# Mvc Ajax Jquery Not refreshing view on post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am new to ajax and mvc... i have a problem with posting back data from jquery. The problem I have is the values are being populated the controller is hit database is updated and then it returns to the page with old data it is not refreshing I have to click f5 to see changes what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Jquery

```
                    var values = 
                        {
                            "PagePartIdentifier": element,
                            "PagePartContent": data
                        }
                        $.post(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Url.Action("UploadData", "Home"))),values,function(data)
                        {
                            // do stuff;
                        });
```

Model

```
public class PagePartModel
{

    public string PagePartIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string PagePartContent { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult UploadData(PagePartModel pagePartm)
    {
        UpdatePage(pagePartm);
        ModelState.Clear();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return Json(new { success = true });

    }
```

Html is rendered from a helper method

```
    public static PagePartModel PageAfterContent(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, int page)
    {
        string part = "AfterContent";
        Blog.PageParts pageParts = new Blog.PageParts();

        PagePartModel thispart = pageParts.GetContentForPageByPart(page, part);
        return thispart;
    }
```

Returns the model for each part to the page

Answer (score 0):

When using $.post, you're sending the data to the server via ajax, so the page never reloads.  I'm not sure what the `UpdatePage(pagePartm);` call in your post method is doing, but since that method is getting called with ajax, it can't change anything on the page.  Now in your success handler on your $.post, you can manipulate the DOM to reflect the success or failure of your $.post call.

Answer (score 0):

In your action, instead of returning your `Json(new { success = true });` you should/could return the data that you want to be displayed on the page,

e.g.

```
return Json(new { pagePartm }); // if that is what should be returned
```

Then modify your `$.post()` to append the data into the DOM somewhere.

e.g.

```
$.post("your_controller_action", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
  function(data){
    doStuff(data); // this is your point of interaction with the returned data
    // or
    $("#my_h3").val(data.pagePartm.PagePartIdentifier);
    $("#my_div").append(data.pagePartm.PagePartContent);
});
```

from the [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Post) documentation.

This will avoid the need to refresh the page to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

jquery ajax post cache property is false ?

```
$.ajax({
         url: '/youraction',
         cache: false,
         type: 'post'
         success: function (data) {


         },
         error: function (e) {
             alert(e.responseText);                            
         }
});
```